# Add-In Global Declarations

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large EXCEL model that has to run routines via add-ins that have common variable. To speed up the process, I would like to create global variable FROM INSIDE the add-in modules. When I try that and then debug the add-in module, any module, excluding the main module, gives me an error the variables are not defined.

```
'Main module in add-in
'----------------------
Global i As Integer, j As Integer
'
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
MsgBox "Macro 1: " & i
'
    i = 100
    Macro2
'
MsgBox "Macro 1: " & i
'
End Sub
'
'
'Separate module in add-in
'-------------------------
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
    MsgBox "Macro 2: " & i
'
i = 200
'
'
    MsgBox "Macro 2: " & i

End Sub
```

error: i is an ambiguous name

Comment: If you really want help you should consider formatting your code so it is readable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Change Global to Public, it shoud work

Comment: Sorry, same ambiguous name error. Reminder: both the main module and the calling modules are in add-ins. This seems to make to difference. Thanks.